# How to insert from multiple places into one table in this situation (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert data into a table that can be used as a report to view when each database had their last successful backup. The table that is being inserted into has name, input_type, status, start_time, end_time, and duration columns, and my SQL is currently:

```
INSERT INTO schema.Backup_Report (input_type, status, start_time, end_time, duration)  
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT INPUT_TYPE, 
             STATUS, 
             START_TIME, 
             END_TIME, 
             elapsed_seconds/60 as duration_in_min 
      FROM v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS 
      ORDER BY end_time desc)
WHERE rownum = 1
AND input_type = 'DB INCR'
AND STATUS = 'COMPLETED';
```

This works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to also insert into the name column, as I have tried using a union in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT name from v$database union
SELECT INPUT_TYPE, 
             STATUS, 
             START_TIME, 
             END_TIME, 
             elapsed_seconds/60 as duration_in_min 
      FROM v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS 
      ORDER BY end_time desc)
```

This gives me an ora-00904 error, as I think it doesn't like the `order by end_time` part.

Comment: You need to find some identifier for the database that is in both v$database and v$rman_backup_job_details that you can join the two queries on.

Comment: And you should probably create a view for this, not insert these results into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT * 
          FROM (SELECT INPUT_TYPE, 
                       STATUS, 
                       START_TIME, 
                       END_TIME, 
                       elapsed_seconds/60 as duration_in_min 
                FROM   v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS 
                ORDER BY
                       END_TIME DESC )
          WHERE ROWNUM     = 1
          AND   INPUT_TYPE = 'DB INCR'
          AND   STATUS     = 'COMPLETED' )
        CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT name from v$database );
```

Comment: @corn503 HTH - If it has answered your question then you can accept the answer to mark the question as closed.